# Notifying listeners during widget disposing

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

If I have a class with ChangeNotifier :

```
class MyClass extends ChangeNotifier {
    int myValue = 0;
    incrementsValue(){
        myValue ++;
        NotifyListeners();
    }
}
```

A widget listening to it :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text('${context.watch<MyClass>().myValue}');
}
```

And a need to call incrementsValue() during widget dispose :

```
@override
dipose(){
    myClass.incrementsValue();
}
```

I get this error :

> This _InheritedProviderScope<MyClass?> widget cannot be marked as
> needing to build because the framework is locked.

Is there a way to avoid this error ?